# How to measure what impedance speaker to use

Tags: speakers

I have an old cassette player, which doesn't have a speaker (it was taken out before). Can I measure somehow, what impedance speaker should I connect to it?

Comment: Directly measure: no you cannot. Most of these speakers are either 32, 16, 8 or 4 ohms. 32 Ohms would be relatively safe but 32 ohm speakers are small and hard to find. You can also just try with an 8 ohm speaker but there's no guarantee that the amplifier section was designed to drive 8 ohms.

Comment: Since distortion rises with current and power is limited by voltage, estimate P , measure V max and compute R and use this or higher

Comment: Why is this question getting voted down? It doesn't violate any posting rules.